# Do rows need an immediate parent in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The ***Bootstrap 3*** docs say:

> Rows must be placed within a `.container` for proper alignment and padding.

Does this mean that one of their ancestors should be a container or that their immediate parent should be a container?

Having looked at the examples, I think the former interpretation is correct as containers have fixed widths for specific display sizes:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  ...
}
```

And as such they cannot be placed inside other components (e.g. `.panel-body`s).

In other words, is the following correct markup in Bootstrap 3?

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Col 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `<div class="row">` and not `<row>`?

Comment: @Skelly, I updated his code to show <div class="row"> instead.

Answer (score 7):

It means that one of their ancestors should be a `.container`.

And your code is correct, as the docs mention:

> Note that, due to padding and fixed widths, containers are not
>   nestable by default.

**Some info on why rows need to be inside `.container`.**

Rows have `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px`.  That's because rows should only contain columns, e.g. `col-md-12`, and those columns have `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px`.  So that negative margin on the row will mean that effectively columns will line up 'flush' with the edges of the grid.

Because of that negative margin, you need to have the `.container` because it has `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;`.  Without that, your rows would go off the page.

**Full width designs**

Of course, if you do wrap everything in `.container` then you'll have a fixed width which is not right for everyone.  So, if you don't want that, you can go against Bootstrap's rules and place your `rows` inside a parent that has `padding: 0 15px` to offset the negative margin on rows (the would cause container to go off the screen and cause a scrollbar).

[This demo shows both situations described above](http://jsbin.com/ifetihe/2/edit).

Comment: Note that now we have `.container-fluid` for full-width designs.

Answer (score 1):

The `.container` class is responsible for the padding and margins of its children. Hence, whatever content you put inside the containers inherhits those properties unless overridden. There's nothing unusual going on here.

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L722) for further information:

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```